# How to limit window width for split-screen and slide-over modes on iPadOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, layout, ipados

I'm looking for the ways to control the size of windows on iPad when the window is in one of the following modes:

- split-screen
- **slide-over**

Mostly interesting for me is how to limit or strictly set the width for window in slide-over mode. I need to make slide-over window narrower.

[image: slit-screen, two windows]
[image: slide-over, one window over another]

Comment: No, at least not now, it is OS feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030) said,

Currently it isn't possible officially because there's not API for the subject.